# How to go around using .slideUp() or .slideDown() only on specific child

Tags: jquery

I currently have multiple items displayed on a page that have their description hidden by default. The description can be shown by pressing the div with the class .morebtn however the jquery code has no way of uniquely identifying which .morebtn relates to which description (.desc)

```
<div>
   <span class="item">Item Name</span>
   <div class="btn addbtn" alt="Add to your basket"></div>
   <div class="btn morebtn" alt="More information"></div>
   <div class="desc">Hello this is a test description for the above item. </div>
<div>
```

There will be multiple instances of the code above depending upon the amount of item entries in my database.
What would be the best way to make it so I can get the morebtn to only show the description of the desc within the same div?

Comment: In the click handler, you can find the next `desc` element like `$(this).next('.desc').toggle()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0o2tLs7L/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("body").on("click",".morebtn",function() {
         var ele = $(this);
         $(this).next(".desc").toggle();
     });
});
```

Comment: that's an odd construction for attaching a click handler. any special reason for not just doing `$(".morebtn").on("click", funct...` ?
(it bubbles up all the way from body to .morebtn in your example, but i can't figure out why you'd want this in this case)

Comment: I am assuming the section will be added dynamically at runtime in realtime. So, I have used event delegation technique.

Comment: This didn't seem to work but I'm not 100% sure how Id test this

Comment: @EnayetHussain, can you please post fiddle or it